# Changing default ArcGIS Home folder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, default

ArcGIS Desktop defaults the Home folder to something like `C:\Users\<username>\Documents\ArcGIS` - creating a folder in the `My Documents` or `Documents` folder depending on the version of Windows.

[image]

Personally I try to keep my GIS work out of the Documents folder, and usually store all my files in a folder called `D:\GIS`.  Primary reason for this was because my work had network stored Documents folders which had a quota of 5mb, which was much much much too small for storing any kind of GIS data.  This is made worse by the fact that Esri Add-ins default to installing into this folder also.

I've been trying to find a way to make ArcGIS default to my `D:\GIS` folder as the Home location *without* first saving an MXD.  I know that I can save an MXD into that folder and it will then become the Home folder for that MXD.  I'd like to be able to open ArcMap and have my files/folders already accessable from that Home folder `D:\GIS` without having to go find it, or even having it as a Folder Connection.

> The Home folder is used by default in ArcMap to save results, store
>   new datasets, and access file-based information. It is the location
>   that is initially used to add new layers to ArcMap and to store new
>   datasets that are created during editing and geoprocessing.
>
> The same is true for nonspatial data. When you export a page layout as
>   PDF, the default location will be the map's home location (the map
>   document's workspace folder).

<sup>[Working with the Home folder](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-arcmap/working-with-the-home-folder-and-default-geodatabase.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_F062132A090B4DDD8976EB3806A5430B)</sup>

I have found several posts (mostly on Esri's Geonet) asking how to do this, but none of these posts have a solution other than the two options I mentioned above (which aren't really a *default*).

How can I force ArcGIS to use my own folder location as the default Home folder without having to save an MXD first?

Comment: I've had to get surly with several users for building map documents using their default.gdb - it not only restricts any future edits to a single workstation but to a specific username/workstation combination... and if *they're* not in the office when last minute changes need to be made then it causes **serious** problems; even though you can access the workstation any files in the user folder are inaccessible! Thanks for this guide, now I can set the default to a location that isn't hobbled by UAC.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am copying the **warning/disclaimer** from Esri's support page on the subject:

> Warning:
>   The instructions below include making changes to essential
>   parts of your operating system.  It is recommended that you backup
>   your operating system and files, including the registry,  before
>   proceeding. Consult with a qualified computer systems professional, if
>   necessary.
>
> Esri **(and Midavalo!)** cannot guarantee results from incorrect modifications while
>   following these instructions;  therefore, use caution and proceed at
>   your own risk.

At ArcGIS 10.0 SP5 Esri introduced the ability to change your default Home folder location by adding a key and value into the Registry.

In the Windows Registry browse to `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ESRI\Desktop10.5\ArcCatalog` and Right-Click > Add > New Key and name the key `DefaultHomeFolder`

[image]

[image]

In that new key, in the right-hand pane, Right-Click > New > String Value and name the string value `Location`

[image]

[image]

Double-click on `Location` to add your desired folder as the new Home location - in my case `D:\GIS`

[image]

[image]

Now when I open ArcMap and use the Catalog pane I see that my Home folder is set by default to `D:\GIS`, so any tools I use now (even without an MXD opened) will save to there unless I change the output folder in the tool parameters.

[image]

This works from ArcGIS 10.5 SP5 onwards.

See Esri's support page - [How To: Set the default Home folder and geodatabase location for new map documents](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000011581)

Unfortunately, the default location does **not** change where the Add-Ins are installed by default.  I know there is a workaround to store them elsewhere, but this Home folder trick doesn't do it.